# Excel : Updating series data erase chart styles

Tags: excel, vba

I'm retrieving in a worksheet data formatted as a csv from a php file on my server.
As I consider I don't know how many lines I will receive, It pushes the data in this worksheet with the options replacing the content of cells if necessary, and deleting the unused ones.
I run a procedure to parse the data of this worksheet to fill another worksheet.
For the same reason as above, I clear the columns of this second worksheet before filling it.

Here is a sample of my procedure :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("data2").Activate
Range("A:B:C:D").Clear

Worksheets("data").Activate
Set my_range = Range("A:A")

For i = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
    'calculations saved in some vars : var1, var2, ...
    Cells(i, 1).Value = var1
    Cells(i, 2).Value = var2
    '...
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

On the second worksheet, I've inserted a chart using data from the two worksheets.
As the number of rows is dynamic, I've declared names to refer to my column. They are set like : `=OFFSET(data!$A$1;0;0;COUNT(data!$A:$A))`

My problem is when I run my procedure, I lose all the styles set for my chart.
Am I doing something wrong ? Is there an option to keep the styles of my chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread your problem, and thought you were losing formatting on your cells. Now I see it's your chart. I have a number of charts that I am doing the same thing as you. I update the Chart Series with VBA and I never lose formatting. Before I clear data, I set all chart series values ={1}. Then I have another macro that sets the series values after I load the data.

Here's a sub I wrote to clear the series before clearing the data:

```
Sub clearChart(chartWs As Worksheet, chartName As String)
  Dim cObj As ChartObject
  Dim i As Integer
  Set cObj = chartWs.ChartObjects(chartName)
  For i = 1 To cObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.count
     cObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "{1}"
     cObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "{1}"
  Next i
End Sub
```

Example:
    clearChart Sheet2, "Chart1"

Hope that helps...

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot